# Jquery- Filter div inside <li>

Tags: jquery

I have a number of div that are listed and I want to be able to add an input field that will allow a user to start typing and the div are filtered according to each div. I'm trying the code below, but it's not working.

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){    
    var search_text = $('#search').val();
    var rg = new RegExp(search_text,'i');
    var liLength=$("#dataList li").length;     
    for (var i = 0; i < liLength; i++) {
        if ($(".address").text().search(rg) || $(".trustee").text().search(rg) || $(".borrower").text().search(rg)) {
            $("#dataList li")[i].style.display="block";
        } else {       
            $("#dataList li")[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANJYR/pbnjcy5u/)

Comment: Check the console - you have quite a few errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `contains` method defined. You can use [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead. Also you need to provide context for search for blocks `.address`, `.trustee` and `.borrower` to search inside individual `li` element:

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var search_text = $('#search').val();
    var rg = new RegExp(search_text, 'i');

    $("#dataList li").each(function() {
        if ($(".address", this).text().match(rg) || $(".trustee", this).text().match(rg) || $(".borrower", this).text().match(rg)) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }    
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pbnjcy5u/1/